# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') on React-native 0.70.6

Tags: java, android, react-native

Currently, I have completed updating my project to React-Native 0.70.6 (The Latest). Everything is working as expected during development (npm run android) and Apk builds process also generates APK without any error. But when I run my Final APK app suddenly crashes without any error. To detect the reason for crash I have used several debugging tools. Which gives me the error as shown below

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. 
Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFr assets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:248)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader $1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundl e(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:277)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactCont ext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1402)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access $1200(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager
$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1108) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I searched everywhere about this problem on the web. I read several posts and got several suggestions that I have implemented in my files.

My android/build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" 
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}

 allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Few configurations of android/app/build.gradle

```
    // other code .....
    project.ext.react = [
      enableHermes: true,  
      entryFile: "index.js",
      bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
      bundleInDebug: true,
      bundleInRelease: true
   ]

   def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
   def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

   android {
      ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
      compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

      defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
        multiDexEnabled true
        
        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            // We configure the CMake build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "-DNODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
     splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // other code ......
 }
```

Detail of java I am using

```
    Openjdk version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 18.0.1.1+0)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 18.0.1.1+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have tried creating a fully new project on react native 0.70.6 and generated a signed apk which worked fine but didn't work with dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problem. Downgrade gradle helps me in my case.

In: `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` i changed version from `7.5.1` to `7.3.3`.

In: `android/build.gradle` i changed  gradle from : `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")` to
`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1")`